# How can one achieve happiness?

Tags: philosophy, rituals, practice

I have heard discussions of Hinduism scriptures telling how to achieve fulfillment, divinity etc but I have yet to hear one talking about how to achieve happiness. Is  this covered in Hinduism? If so, what is the procedure?

Comment: Well in one simple line: get detached from everything, what I mean by everything is be it joy or sadness, money or no money, family or no family, ups or downs in life and so on, just be equanimous; don't let anything bother you or alter the stable state of your mind. Do your karma, forget about the fruits! Observe everything as it, don't judge anyone or anything!

Comment: I would suggest Rupert Spira's latest book https://www.amazon.com/You-Are-Happiness-Seek-Uncovering/dp/1684030129 or the audiobook version from his website https://rupertspira.com/.  Not Hinduism per se but closely matched with Vedanta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following perspectives from Swami Sivananda (from the Divine Life Society) might serve useful in the Pursuit of Happiness, as per Hinduism paradigm.

#### What is Happiness?

In Hinduism, the idea of Happiness is not found in sensual objects in relation to any bodily attachments, rather, in the experience of that all pervading Self (*Advaitic*), or in the Kingdom of the one's personal favourite god (*non-Advaitic*) and in his service.

> ##### THE SOURCE OF HAPPINESS<sup>**§**</sup>
>
> There is no happiness at all in any of the objects of the world. There
> is not an iota of happiness in objects, because they are insentient.
> Even the sensual pleasure is a reflection of the Atmic bliss only. It
> is sheer ignorance to think that we derive any pleasure from the
> sense-objects or from the mind.

- One must detest the worldly definitions of pleasure and happiness, which are but temporary. The real happiness is in the Supreme, or in the Self.

> ##### REAL HAPPINESS IS WITHIN
>
> Real happiness is within you. It is in the Atman. It is subjective. It
> manifests when the mind is concentrated. When the Indriyas are
> withdrawn from the objects outside, when the mind is one-pointed, when
> there is Vasana-kshya and Manonasa, when you become desireless and
> thoughtless, Atmic bliss begins to dawn, spiritual Ananda begins to
> thrill.
>
> The musk is in the navel of the deer, but it runs here and there to
> smell it. The chain is in the neck of the damsel, but she runs hither
> and thither in search of it.

#### How to achieve happiness? The Methods?

> ##### SENSUAL PLEASURE AND SPIRITUAL BLISS
>
> Spiritual bliss is the highest bliss. Spiritual bliss is bliss of
> one’s own Soul. It is transcendental bliss. It is independent of
> objects. It is continuous, uniform and eternal. It is enjoyed by the
> sage only.
>
> .......
>
> **Purify the mind by Japa, Satsanga, charity, control of mind,
> self-restraint, selfless service, study of the Gita, the Upanishads,
> Yoga-Vasishtha, and other religious scriptures, practice
> of Yama and Niyama, Pranayama, Vairagya and Tyaga. You will then get a
> proper instrument for meditation, a calm, sharp, subtle, one-pointed
> mind. Start meditation with the help of this instrument for three
> hours in the morning and three hours at night. Then a new kind of
> indescribable Ananda will dawn in you. You will be convinced of a
> supersensual spiritual bliss. You will have to feel this spiritual
> Ananda yourself.** You will have to eat it yourself. Can you explain the
> sexual happiness to a boy of twelve ? Can you explain the happiness of
> sugar-candy to a boy who has not tasted the same ? No, you cannot. The
> boy himself must eat sugar-candy. He must, when he has grown up, taste
> the carnal pleasure.

## To Conclude -

In the words of Swami Sivananda, from [another article](https://www.dlshq.org/discourse/true-happiness/) 'True Happiness'.

> - True happiness lies in virtue and inner soul and not in earthly
>   possessions. Man has to rise up above the world consciousness through
>   daily meditation. He should ever attempt to enter the divine
>   consciousness. He should manifest the divine through Sadhana or
>   concentration. He should transform the human nature into divine nature
>   by developing Daivi Sampat. **He should cut asunder the network of
>   desires which brings distress and misery in the end through Japa,
>   prayer, meditation and Satsang.**
> - **Never run away from your jobs. One should do all actions in a spirit of detachment**. One should leave the world and the objects of the world, as everything is perishable. Love the Lord seated in all.
> - All evil habits can be eradicated by constant Abhyas and absolute Vairagya. Ever feel they are the impediments in the spiritual path. **Develop a strong desire for God-realisation only.**

---

**§**

Quoting from [the article - 'HAPPINESS' By SRI SWAMI SIVANANDA](https://www.dlshq.org/messages/happiness/) taken from the book “Bliss Divine”.